# how can I set the reducer's return value to state object in component in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I have one component as below. I am calling on api on its componentDidMount() event. I am not getting why am I not getting its prop value first time when component renders. Also I am not sure why component is rendering 2 times. I have below code.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AgmtTable from "./AgmtTable";
import * as AgmtAction from "../redux/actions/AgmtAction";

class AgmtContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  fetch Agmt details.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(
      AgmtAction.getAgmtsForCustomer(
        this.props.match.params.custID,
        this.props.match.params.source,
        this.props.token
      )
    );
    console.log("componentDidMount", this.props.Agmts);
  }

  getHeaader = () => {
    var tableHeadings = [
      "Agmt ID",
      "Start Date",
      "End Date",
    ];
    return tableHeadings.map((key) => {
      return <th key={key}> {key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  getRowsData = () => {
    console.log("in row data", this.props.Agmts);//here I cant see a data though its present in mapStateToProps() function. I am getting error as this.props.agreements.map is not a function.
     if (this.props.Agmts) {
       return this.props.Agmts.map((value) => {
         const {
           Agmt_ID,
           Agmt_START_DATE,
           End_DATE,

         } = value;
         return (
           <tr key={Agmt_ID} className="clickable-row active">
             <td> {Agmt_ID} </td>
             <td> {Agmt_START_DATE} </td>
             <td> {End_DATE} </td>
             </tr>
         );
       });
     }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <table
            id="display-table"
            className="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-sm"
          >
            <tbody>
              <tr>{this.getHeaader()}</tr>
              {this.getRowsData()}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    Agmts: state.AgmtsDetails.AgmtsData,//here I have a data
    token: state.login.userDetails.token,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AgmtContainer);
```

Also how can I use the mapStateToProps values to set in state object. When I am running above code I am getting error as this.props.agmts.map is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatch is asynchronous, so you either need to watch for result to be updated in your Redux store with `componentDidUpdate` **or** directly return the result from the reducer.

When you get the result, you can manipulate it and store it in local state to reference in your render. Note that unless you need to reference the result in another component somewhere, then you don't need to store it in Redux, you can handle it all in within the component.

**Subscribing to the store with `componentDidUpdate`:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(
    AgmtAction.getAgmtsForCustomer(
      this.props.match.params.custID,
      this.props.match.params.source,
      this.props.token
    )
  );
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (JSON.stringify(prevProps.Agmts) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.Agmts)) {
    // this is the result of the dispatch
    console.log(this.props.Agmts);
  }
}
```

**Returning the result directly back:**

```
// in your AgmtAction.getAgmtsForCustomer action
export const getAgmtsForCustomer = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  return axios
    .get(..........
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(..........
        return res.data;
      })
    .catch((err) => {
      ...
    });
};

// in your `AgmtContainer` component
...
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(
    AgmtAction.getAgmtsForCustomer(
      this.props.match.params.custID,
      this.props.match.params.source,
      this.props.token
    )
  ).then((res) => {
    // this is the result of the dispatch
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Comment: you just not only solved my issue but has given extra info on redux use which help me reduce unnecessary store updates. I wish I could vote your answer 100 times. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

In getRowsData function where you are getting error "map is not a function" is due to the data you are getting in this.props.Agmts must be an object type. (Object encloses in curly brackets {}).

You can apply map function only on array not on an object. (Array encloses in square brackets [])

Comment: This was also one of issue. But after making it array  I was not getting values. After making changes as per below code it worked smoothly. Thanks for this help.